# Retrieve users' IP addresses and store them in a database table?

Tags: mysql, ip

I have a MySQL query that inserts the content of a form into my database.

Along side inserting these values, I also want to discover and insert the users IP address. This is for the site's protection. This way if a user is constantly posting harmful content their ip can be blocked.

Here's my script. I am trying to use `" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "` but its not working for me. Can someone please show me a way of doing this.

I'm trying to store the IP in a column in my table called 'ip' (int(10) Atributes: UNSIGNED NULL:No Default:None)

UPDATE:

When I change the column 'ip' to a VARCHAR(48) I get this printed in the column rather than a full IP: `::1`

```
<?php

ob_start();

// check if the review form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['review_content'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['review_recipient'])) {
        $content = $_POST['review_content'];
        $review_recipient = $_POST['review_recipient'];

        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $content = stripslashes($content);
                $review_recipient = stripslashes($review_recipient);
        }

        $regex = "/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?/";
        $replacement = "[blocked url]";

        $regex2 = "/(.*)\b(BLOCKED WORDS GO HERE!!!!)\b(.*)/";
$replacement2 = "[blocked content]<br/><br/>This content was blocked because it was deemed offensive or inappropriate.";

$replacement3 = "[blocked username]";


        $review_recipient = preg_replace(Array($regex, $regex2),Array($replacement, $replacement3),$_POST['review_recipient']);
        //$profile_id = intval($_POST['profile_id']); //dont know how you get this
        $content = preg_replace(Array($regex, $regex2),Array($replacement, $replacement2),$_POST['review_content']);


        //We check if all the fields are filled
        if($_POST['review_content']!='') {
            if($_POST['review_recipient']!='') {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_reviews (id, from_user_id, from_guest, ip, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '-1', '".$review_recipient."', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
                mysql_query($sql, $connection);

                $_SESSION['message']="<div class=\"infobox-review-sent\"><strong>Thank You</strong> - Your review has been sent and is awaiting approval.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>";

                header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
            }
        }

    }

} } }

?>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, please use PDO mysql_query commands are deprecated.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is a string like `192.168.55.7`. Does that look like an integer to you?

Comment: im not getting any errors, just nothings being inserted into the table. @Barmar so if i change the ip column to varchar(48) would that work?

Comment: You're not even checking for errors, so how do you know? You need to check the return value of `mysql_query`, and print `mysql_error()` if it's false. You can use `ip2long()` to convert an IP address to an integer, or you can store it in a `char(15)`.

Comment: `::1` is the IPv6 address of `localhost`.

Comment: @Barmar ok tahnks so once i put it on my server it should show a normal ip?

Comment: Yes. If they use IPv6 you'll see addresses with `:` in them, if they use IPv4 you'll see addresses with `.`.

Comment: Remember that almost ALL browsers run behind NAT firewalls, many of which have DHCP (dynamic) IP addresses. This means that one IP address can designate many individual computers, and an IP address doesn't necessarily identify the same host (or set of hosts) from day to day.  Blocking based solely on IP will regularly block innocent third parties.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) to store and INET_NTOA when retrieving:

```
<?php

ob_start();

// check if the review form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['review_content'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['review_recipient'])) {
        $content = $_POST['review_content'];
        $review_recipient = $_POST['review_recipient'];

        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $content = stripslashes($content);
                $review_recipient = stripslashes($review_recipient);
        }

        $regex = "/(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?/";
        $replacement = "[blocked url]";

        $regex2 = "/(.*)\b(BLOCKED WORDS GO HERE!!!!)\b(.*)/";
$replacement2 = "[blocked content]<br/><br/>This content was blocked because it was deemed offensive or inappropriate.";

$replacement3 = "[blocked username]";


        $review_recipient = preg_replace(Array($regex, $regex2),Array($replacement, $replacement3),$_POST['review_recipient']);
        //$profile_id = intval($_POST['profile_id']); //dont know how you get this
        $content = preg_replace(Array($regex, $regex2),Array($replacement, $replacement2),$_POST['review_content']);


        //We check if all the fields are filled
        if($_POST['review_content']!='') {
            if($_POST['review_recipient']!='') {

                $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_reviews (id, from_user_id, from_guest, ip, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '-1', '".$review_recipient."', 'INET_ATON(" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "'), '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
                mysql_query($sql, $connection);

                $_SESSION['message']="<div class=\"infobox-review-sent\"><strong>Thank You</strong> - Your review has been sent and is awaiting approval.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>";

                header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
            }
        }

    }

} } }

?>
```

Do be aware, though, this will not work if you're using IPv6. If that is the case, the INET6_ATON and INET6_NTOA functions will be necessary.